# how to uninstall geos in macosx

Tags: macos, postgis, geo

How do I uninstall geos in mac osx

When i do
    sudo uninstall geos
I get this error

```
Uninstall Began...
Uninstall Failed...
Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

I have to uninstall it propely because I need to install a newer version . When I installed a newer version even the it shows

```
geos-config --version
3.1.1
```

It was present somewhere in my system. Installation for a new one was successful for some features of postgis is not working and and they are picking up 3.1.1 geos.

I will thankful if someone helps me out here.